# Collision detection with boundingSphere

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection, bounding-volume

For each mesh (`THREE.Object3D`) Three.js provide a very handy properties - `boundingSphere` and `boundingSphere` that have `intersectsSphere` and `isIntersectionBox` methods.

With all this I thought I can use it for simple collision detection but when I try it appears that collision happens all the time because (I tried `boundingSphere`) boundingSphere.center is always in `(0, 0, 0);` So If I want to check collisions between 2 meshes I should for each object - clone `boundingSphere` object and then get it world coordinates and only then to use `intersectsSphere`.

something like this:

```
var bs = component.object.geometry.boundingSphere.clone();
bs.center.setFromMatrixPosition(component.object.matrixWorld);
...
if (_bs.intersectsSphere(bs)){
```

is this how it suppose to be used or am I missing something and there are more convenient way of doing collisions detection based on boundingBox/boundingSphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do collision detection with bounding boxes you need the boxes in the world coordinate system. The bounding volumes in the `intersectsSphere` and `isIntersectionBox` properties of the mesh are in the local coordinate system of the object.

You can do like you did: clone the volumes and move them to the correct position in the world coordinate system, that is a good solution.

Otherwise you can also set a new box from your meshes and do collision using those boxes. Let's say you have a `THREE.Mesh` called `mesh` then you can do:

```
sphere = new THREE.Sphere.setFromPoints( mesh.vertices );

box = new THREE.Box3.setFromObject( mesh );
```

---

A little tip. During development it can be nice to see the bounding boxes in your scene, for this you can use [the `THREE.BoundingBoxHelper`](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Helpers/BoundingBoxHelper):

```
var helper = new THREE.BoundingBoxHelper( mesh );
scene.add( helper );
```

Comment: but why coordinates in `intersectsSphere` is local? it makes `isIntersectionBox` useless, unless some one want to check intersection with local objects...

Comment: @SET There is probably a good reason for that. Like I said to get the bounding box of something in the world coordinate system you can simply do `box = new THREE.Box3.setFromObject( mesh );`. It is also in my answer. I would say that it contains all you need...